# How to convert alaw(8000,1) to ulaw(g711) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to convert alaw(8000,1) to ulaw(g711) with ffmpeg?

I try this but wrong

```
ffmpeg -i test.alaw -codec:a copy -f mulaw  test.ulaw
```

Comment: Why do you have "-acodec:copy" if you are trying to convert the audio format?   Should it not be -codec:a ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use ffmpeg to convert alaw to ulaw,how to do it?@Community

Comment: @davidgo thanks for your comment. the example is not correct ,I need the true answer